# login form does not work with the password

Tags: php

I have problem with log in form. 
I successfully connect to db. if I use only user name it checks in db, and if user name exists it redirect to another page. If I use password it won't log in. 
Below is code:

```
<?php

// check _POST data
$myusername=( isset($_POST['myusername']) ) ? $_POST['myusername'] : false;
$mypassword=( isset($_POST['mypassword']) ) ? $_POST['mypassword'] : false;

if( $myusername === false || $mypassword === false ) die('Access forbidden! Go away!');

// hash password
$encrypted_pass=md5($mypassword);


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // username
$password="le30mu09"; // password
$db_name="infobiz_db2"; // Database name
$tbl_name="jos_users"; // Table name

// Replace database connect functions depending on database you are using.
$link=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$encrypted_pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($link);
if(!$result) {
    die('No database' .mysql_error());
}

// Replace counting function based on database you are using.
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  session_register("myusername");
  session_register("mypassword");
  header("location:login_success.php");
} 
else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

I really got confused here and not able to find solution

Comment: Is your password saved as md5() in the database?

Comment: Can you compare PHP's md5 hash with the one in your database? Does the sql query return an error?

Comment: It can't possibly be helping that you aren't sanitizing your database inputs.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to re-write query as below by using proper quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='". $myusername . "' and Password='" . $encrypted_pass . "'"
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, will it? Since the string is double-quotes, PHP will interpolate variables directly, without having to concatenate everything.

Comment: variables within single-quote are used as such without their values

Comment: echo '$a' (prints '$a') is different from echo "$a" (prints value of $a)

Comment: but $myusername and $encrypted_pass are inside single-quote

Comment: Single quotes will be printed and are sufficent to enclose those strings: his original code looks like `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='MyUserName' and Password='0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'";`

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter - it's the quotes that delimit the string that are important. `echo ("'$a'")` will still interpolate the value of `$a` inside the string - the single quotes there have no effect on how the string is handled.

Comment: then i dont see any other issue with the code. May be a config issue then like db password wrong or something